# Can you use inter-rater reliability to measure reliability of a whole measure with items measuring different things? (Krippendorff's Alpha or similar)

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

Let's say that you have one case study, where 30 raters are asked to apply a measure that has 5 items. Can you compute a single Krippendorff's Alpha (kalpha) value across all 5 items (that are the same data type but different questions) for the single case study, to measure inter-rater reliability of 30 raters?